# How to use Firebase with a linux based client app for bidirectional messages communication with server

Tags: python, c++, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've seen Google's documentation and a lot of examples over the internet about how to use Firebase within Android / iOS applications, but I want to develop a client Firebase application which runs on a linux machine.

My requirements are:

- Client runs on linux environment (either writtern in C++ or python).
- Server is written in Javascript (NodeJS).
- Server and client should have bi-directional communication between them using firebase realtime database.

I've seen also the firebase REST api, but I assume that is not good enough for me since I haven't seen a client listener api that listens on a something like `onValueChanged`.

**Question:**

How can I implement a linux-based app in C++ or python that listens to messages from server (data changes) using a listener, without having to call some `get` function each and every few seconds (just like NodeJS have the `ref.on("child_changed",...)`  or  `ref.on("value",...)`?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: not sure about the C++ SDK from Firebase. But my understanding is, only the iOS, Android, and JS SDs provide database listeners. That is definitely true for the python SDK. (Essentially boils down to how the SDK communicates with Firebase, plain HTTP or WebSockets.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is not official library for Realtime Database in Python but there are some third party wrappers around REST API.

Specifically I would look at [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) library which also supports listening to live changes https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#streaming

For more information, libraries or other languages look at this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Answer (score 1):

Google offers a C++ SDK you can download it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup).

There is also a tutorial on the bottom of the page, but if you really want to dig into some code, [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp) is the quickstart code on github from google with examples for each category on Firebase.

Google has also implemented a Game for demonstration purposes in C++ for Desktop OSs. [here](https://github.com/google/zooshi) There you can find more advanced features and code samples.

I have only tried it with an XCode project on Mac OS X, and it works fine. I have no code for real time database but you should find the sample project in the github repo. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp

I hope this helps!

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you try to use a Realtime Database triggers for C++ (that's is currently on beta) that allows you to simulate the same workflow as on JS?
From my point of view, it is the best way to get it to work as you want.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: Sorry i didn't see in the link you sent a beta API for C++ or python implementation, API that google offers is just in NodeJS. Can you please refer me to a code example written in C++ or python or even any other language other then JS/NodeJS?

Comment: Most likely, that was overall info for any non JS/Java lang. 
I don't actually know, but this should help you:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/retrieve-data
There is documented event listeners for value changes. So, you need to dig more deeply into documentation for triggers for C++.